# How do I update Scrapy from the Terminal?

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, scrapy, uninstallation

I'm currently running Scrapy v0.18, and I'd like to update to the latest stable version 0.22. My biggest issue at the moment is that I can't figure out why the latest version won't install. I used the command `sudo easy_install -U scrapy`, but that resulted in the error message as follows:

```
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
conftest.c:1: fatal error: error closing -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccgmNJrm.out (No such file or directory)
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed

Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
twisted/test/raiser.c:1440: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccriYrDV.out (No such file or directory)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm not very experienced with the command line. How can I update Scrapy to the latest version successfully?

Comment: Have you tried using `pip`?  At the very least the error messages should be more comprehensible. It may be available in your software sources via `sudo apt-get install python-pip` or via `sudo easy_install pip` Then do `sudo pip install scrapy`

Comment: I used pip when I installed scrapy the first time. My issue with pip is that it wouldn't install the latest version of scrapy since I already have the old version installed. I could indeed understand why pip kept deciding to simply leave me high and dry, but I couldn't find a workaround. Is there a command-line way to uninstall the old version of scrapy before installing the latest version?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now that the question has been clarified that the initial install was via `pip`, the best way to upgrade would be:

`sudo pip install --upgrade scrapy`

Comment: That appears to have updated by Scrapy version. But now I have a new issue! What does the following line mean? `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Twisted>=10.0.0`

Comment: Not sure if that's related.  If it's something else you should start a new question.  Anyway, did you try `sudo pip install --upgrade twisted`?

Comment: I just did, and I got the following error:

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/Twisted-8.2.0-py2.6.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'`

Comment: Even with `sudo`? Make sure it's `sudo pip install --upgrade twisted`.  Commands run as `sudo` should never encounter `Permission denied` errors unless they are being grossly misused.

Comment: none of them works for me in Ubuntu 14.04 and it still uses 2017-03-02 20:25:02-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4